# push View Controller in disptached block cause chaos

Tags: ios, objective-c

there are three view controllers in my program.
I have pushed view controller B from view controller A.
"self.navigationController pushViewcontroller: B Animated: YES"
And then, I dispatch a block by the interface in A, what i do in the block is to push the viewcontroller C from A, "self.navigationController pushViewController:C Animated: YES".

Last, pop B. "self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated: YES". And the dispatched block works to push C.

Then the problem come in, the view is presented as A, B and C overlaped together, I mean I can see items in both A, B and C.

Why? I can not push view controllers in block ?

Comment: Anything related to UI must be done on the main thread.